# my system V init script don't return

Tags: sysv

This is script content, located in /etc/init.d/myserviced:

```
#!/lib/init/init-d-script

DAEMON="/usr/local/bin/myprogram.py"
NAME="myserviced" 
DESC="The description of my service"
```

When I start the service (either by calling it directly or by calling `sudo service myserviced start`), I can see program `myprogram.py` run, but it did not return to command prompt.

I guess there must be something that I misunderstood, so what is it?

The system is Debian, running on a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more works, I finally solved this issue. There are 2 major reasons:

- `init-d-script` actually calls `start-stop-daemon`, who don't work well with scripts specified via `--exec` option. When killing scripts, you should only specify `--name` option. However, as `init-d-script` always fill `--exec` option, it cannot be used with script daemons. I have to write the sysv script by myself.
- `start-stop-daemon` won't magically daemonize the thing you provide. So the executable provided to `start-stop-daemon` should be daemonized itself, but not a regular program.